CSS loaded but failed to apply when using Django
These are my folders:

my setting.py:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'blog','static'),
]

my html:
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lexie's blog</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
</head>

Bootstrap is working but the stylesheet I wrote won't override the Bootstrap.
I have tried to install whitenoise which fixed my previous MIME problem. And I have tried to change the static path. Also, python manage.py collectstatic was tried.
I have checked the network using inspect, when refreshing page, it does show the blog.css has been loaded with 200 GET. And when clicking the URL 127.0.0.1:800/static/css/blog.css, it will show the source code of blog.css
I am using my localhost and I have checked the way it interpret css, it is text/css, so I think there is no problem with interpreting.

I think no need to include "blog" in setting.py file. I mean instant of os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'blog','static'), just os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static') should work.

If the file can be loaded successfully then this is markup/css only problem. Show your template element and related css classes.
